# create password for external Hard Drive

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive, password-protection

how can I make a password for my external hard disk easily & effectively? Do I need third party tools or I can do It from windows?

thanks <3

Comment: Have you tried to search first? What did you find? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Windows does not specifically support password protecting external mass storage devices.  Strictly speaking it does not support password protecting any directory.  It is important to point out, as an Administrator on any machine, permissions can be changed on an external mass storage device.  Which means setting the permissions on a mass storage device is pointless, if the user you are trying to prevent from accessing it, is an Administrator on their own machine (and the external device can be connected to that machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are trying to encrypt your hard drive (Encrypting it with a password) then there are two options:
1) If you have Windows 10 Pro, Bitlocker is installed by default. You can turn in on in This PC-> Right Click on Drive, Bitlocker Drive Encryption. This will bring up a pop up window to encrypt your external drive.
2) If you don't have Windows 10 Pro, you will need 3rd party software. You can use something like VeraCrypt: https://www.veracrypt.fr/ to encrypt an external drive.

To decrypt the drive at a later time, you would have to have either VeraCrypt or Bitlocker on the computer that you decrypt it with (Or even read the drive). Other than that I don't know of any other ways to password protect a drive. Bitlocker and Veracrypt may also have lack in compadability between operating systems, so if you plan on using it anywhere else, you might want to think about that.

Comment: the problem with all encryption technologies is that of mobility. Might be worth extending your answer to discuss caveats of encryption. E.g. BitLocker encrypted drives come with BitLocker-To-Go which only works from Windows 7 onwards, has limited support in Linux (through third-party apps and drivers) etc.